# Chrome Selenium IDE 3.4.5 extension "execute script" command not storing as variable

Tags: selenium, random, selenium-ide, execute

I am trying to create a random number generator:

```
Command | Tgt | Val |

store | tom | tester

store | dominic | envr
```

execute script `| Math.floor(Math.random()*11111); | number`

```
type | id=XXX | ${tester}.${dominic}.${number}
```

Expected result:

```
tom.dominic.0   <-- random number
```

Instead I get this:

```
tom.dominic.${number}
```

I looked thru all the resources and it seems the recent selenium update/version has changed the approach and I cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is 2 years old, but it's a fairly common one, so I'll answer it and see if there are other answers that address it.

If you want to assign the result of a script run by the "execute script" in Selenium IDE to a Selenium variable, you have to return the value from JavaScript. So instead of

`execute script | Math.floor(Math.random()*11111); | number`

you need

`execute script | return Math.floor(Math.random()*11111); | number`

Also, in your final assignment that puts the 3 pieces together, you needed `${envr}` instead of `${dominic}`.